# <input type="radio">+<select>

Tags: javascript, html, input, select, radio

Есть 4 инпута type=radio + select, изначально select disabled Вопрос - нужен скрипт, который бы при клике по любому инпуту делал его селект активным, и дизэйблил другие селекты инпутов

```
<div class="btn"><input type="radio" name="name"><select disabled><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></div>
<div class="btn"><input type="radio" name="name"><select disabled><option>3</option><option>4</option></select></div>
<div class="btn"><input type="radio" name="name"><select disabled><option>5</option><option>6</option></select></div>
<div class="btn"><input type="radio" name="name"><select disabled><option>7</option><option>8</option></select></div>
```

```html
<div class="btn"><input type="radio" name="name">
  <select disabled>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="btn"><input type="radio" name="name">
  <select disabled>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="btn"><input type="radio" name="name">
  <select disabled>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="btn"><input type="radio" name="name">
  <select disabled>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Через JS. Но мне кажется там проще упростить до одного селекта, в который будет вставляться разные опции, зависимо от выбора инпута.

Comment: "Вопрос - нужен скрипт" - ??

Comment: `input[name="name"] + select { display: none; } input[name="name"]:checked + select { display: inline-block; } ` - по той же схеме можно добавить прозрачный блок, который будет поверх select, и накроет его, делая недоступным.

Answer (score 3):

Без скрипта, на *CSS*

```css
input[type="radio"]+select {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .5;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+select {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <input type="radio" name="name">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <input type="radio" name="name">
  <select>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <input type="radio" name="name">
  <select>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="btn">
  <input type="radio" name="name">
  <select>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну да, не совсем удачное решение. С кнопкой `Tab` проблемы.